# Why am I getting an IndexError

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write some code that will take an array of numbers and print a string representation of the range of the numbers.

```
def rng (arr)
  str = arr[0].to_s 
  idx = 1
  arr.each do |i| 
    next if arr.index(i) == 0
    if arr[arr.index(i)-1] == i - 1  
      unless str[idx - 1] == "-"
        str[idx] = "-" 
      #else next
      end
      #puts "if statement str: #{str}, idx: #{idx}"
    else
      str[idx] = arr[arr.index(i)-1].to_s
      idx += 1
      str[idx] = ","+ i.to_s
    end
    idx += 1
  end
    puts "str = #{str} and idx = #{idx}"
end

rng [0, 1, 2, 3, 8] #"0-3, 8"
```

I get this error:

```
arrayRange_0.rb:9:in `[]=': index 3 out of string (IndexError)
```

Can anyone explain why? When I uncomment the `else next` it works. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

When you get that error, `str` contains the value `0-` which is only 2 characters long - therefore it can't be indexed to the position of 3.

Add this line before line 9, which is causing your error:

```
puts "str = #{str}, idx = #{idx}"
```

It will output:

```
str = 0, idx = 1
str = 0-, idx = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it:

```
def rng(arr)
  ranges = []
  arr.each do |v|
    if ranges.last && ranges.last.include?(v-1)
      # If this is the next consecutive number
      # store it in the second element
      ranges.last[1] = v
    else
      # Add a new array with current value as the first number
      ranges << [v]
    end
  end
  # Make a list of strings from the ranges
  # [[0,3], [8]] becomes ["0-3", "8"]
  range_strings = ranges.map{|range| range.join('-') }
  range_strings.join(', ')
end


p rng [0, 1, 2, 3, 8]
# results in "0-3, 8"
```

Like the previous answer says, your index is outside of the string